# Rolle's Theorem

Tags: calculus

The question reads:

"Find a continuous function $f$ and an interval $(a,b)$ such that $f(a)=f(b)$, but there is no number $c$ in $(a,b)$ such that $f'(c)=0$. Explain why your function doesn't violate the theorem"

$\operatorname{abs}(x)$ is an example of this, but the teacher said that the function must also be differentiable in $(a,b)$. I can't think of a function that is differentiable but doesn't agree with Rolle's theorem even though it meets the conditions.

Comment: Technically, $\frac1x-x$ is continuous and differentiable. So is $\tan x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rolle's theorem states:

If a

- real-valued function $f$
- is continuous on a proper closed interval $[a, b]$,
- differentiable on the open interval $(a, b)$,
- and f(a) = f(b),

then there exists at least one $c$ in the open interval $(a, b)$ such that
$f'(c) = 0$.

Your problem statement says that you should find $f$ that has the second and fourth property and (according to the teacher's later addition) also the third property. I suggest you drop the first property then.

> For example let $f(t)=e^{it}$ on $[0,2\pi]$.